# What does (.+_)* mean when using Henry Spencer regular expression library?

Tags: regex

With reference to Henry spencer regex library I want to know the difference between `(.+_)*` and `(.)*`.

`(.+_)*` tries to match the string from back as well. From my understanding `.` matches any single character, `.+` will mean non zero occurrences of that character. `_` will mean space or { or } or , etc.

Parentheses imply that any one can be considered for a match and the final `*` signifies 0 or more occurrences.

I feel `(.)*` would also achieve the same thing. The `+` after `.` might be redundant.

Can someone explain me the subtle difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

For example, `aa aa` will be matched by `(.+_)*` but not by `(._)*` because the latter expects only one character before the space.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. What would be the difference if it was (.+_)* Vs (.)* . aa aa will be matched by (.)* as well. Will there be any strings which is matched by the former but not by the latter? Or will there be any strings matched by the latter but not by the former?

Comment: `(.)*` will match everything, the point represents every possible character, so there is no string that will match the former and not match this regex. Anything that doesn't contain a space will be matched by the latter but not by the former.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall that underscore has any special meaning. The special thing about Henry Spencer regex library is that it combines both regex engine techniques - deterministic and non-determinstic.

This has a pro and a con.

The pro is that you regexps will be the fastest possible, simply built, while in other engines you might to use look a head and advanced regexp techniques (like making it fail early if there is no match) to achieve the same speed.

The con is that the entire regexp will be either greedy or non greedy. That is, if you used the * or + withouth a following a ?, then the entire regexp will be greedy, even though you use ? after that. If the first time you use a * or + you follow it by a ?, then the entire regexp will be non greedy.

This makes it a **slightly** trickier to craft the regexp, but really slightly.

The Henry Speced library is the engine behind **tcl**'s `regexp` command, which makes this language very efficient for regexps.

Answer (score 1):

As I know the `_` doesn't have a special meaning, it is just a "_". See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html)

Your two regexes are not the same.

1. `(._)*` will match one character followed by an underscore (if the underscore has a special meaning in your implementation replace "underscore" by that meaning), this sequence will be matched 0 or more times, e.g. "`a_%_._?_`"
2. `(.+_)*` will match **at least one** character followed by an underscore, this sequence will be matched 0 or more times, e.g. "`abc45_%_.;,:_?#'+*~_`"

`(.+_)*` will match everything that can be matched by `(._)*` but not the other way round.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I edited the question to find out the difference between (.+_)* and (.)*. I could not think of any strings matching the former but not the latter or even the vice-versa.

Comment: I think you should read a basic regex tutorial. The brackets are just for grouping (and capturing). So the brackets in your second expression are useless, unless you want to capture the last matched character. The second will match every string (till the first newline character). The first one requires a space character at the end.